# Why can one column of the pandas DataFrame not be filled?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, nan

I'm having some problems iteratively filling a pandas DataFrame with two different types of values. As a simple example, please consider the following initialization:

**IN:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan,
                  index=range(5),
                  columns=['date', 'price'])

df
```

**OUT:**

```
    date    price
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
```

When I try to fill one row of the DataFrame, it won't adjust the value in the `date` column. Example:

**IN:**

```
df.iloc[0]['date'] = '2022-05-06'
df.iloc[0]['price'] = 100
df
```

**OUT:**

```
    date    price
0   NaN 100.0
1   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
```

I'm suspecting it has something to do with the fact that the default `np.nan` value cannot be replaced by a `str` type value, but I'm not sure how to solve it. Please note that changing the `date` column's type to `str` does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: df.date[0]='2022-05-06'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because `df.iloc[0]` creates a temporary Series, which is what you update, not the original DataFrame.

If you need to mix positional and label indexing you can use:

```
df.loc[df.index[0], 'date'] = '2022-05-06'
df.loc[df.index[0], 'price'] = 100
```

output:

```
         date  price
0  2022-05-06  100.0
1         NaN    NaN
2         NaN    NaN
3         NaN    NaN
4         NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `loc()` as shown below may work better:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan,
                  index=range(5),
                  columns=['date', 'price'])
print(df)
df.loc[0, 'date'] = '2022-05-06'
df.loc[0, 'price'] = 100
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   date  price
0   NaN    NaN
1   NaN    NaN
2   NaN    NaN
3   NaN    NaN
4   NaN    NaN
         date  price
0  2022-05-06  100.0
1         NaN    NaN
2         NaN    NaN
3         NaN    NaN
4         NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I imagine OP wanted to mix positional and label indexing ;)

Comment: @mozway Perhaps, though I note that an index was explicitly specified in df initialization. I guess we can't be sure without asking OP.

Comment: To be honest, I'm having a problem where I want to fill a DataFrame that consists of a MultiIndex. And for some reason it seems that I cannot fill it using the accepted answer. I guess I should've included a MultiIndex DataFrame in my example to start with.

Comment: @hendrikjanvdb yes, it's always best to include something that replicates your exact use case. The solution would be different for a MultiIndex depending on the target level. Feel free to ask a new question ;)

Comment: @hendrikjanvdb You can ask a new question containing the multiindex example you have in mind.

Comment: I've just fixed it! It was a matter of first calling the column in question, followed by the ```.at[]``` function (since ```.set_value()``` has been deprecated) using all indices.

Example: ```df.booking_date.at[x, y, z] = '2022-05-06'```